# Two-Phase Simplex Method Problem

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I have this problem:
[image]

I need help solving it. I tried constructing an auxiliary problem and I got stuck because I found it’s unbounded...which should not be. Here’s what I got as the auxiliary LP:

$max\begin{pmatrix}5 & 1 & 10 & 0 & 0\end{pmatrix}x-11$

such that$\begin{pmatrix}3&-1&6&1&0\\2&2&4&0&1\end{pmatrix}x=\begin{pmatrix}5\\6\end{pmatrix}$

Please help me solve for the canonical form. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I cannot comprehend the red part: .$..=\binom{-5}{6}\color{red}{x=}$. It does not make sense to me

Comment: And your objective function does not correspond with the obj. function of the exercise.